# Сортировка компонентов в NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Подскажите пожалуйста, как установить сортировку компонентов в пакете по типу. Работаю в IDE NetBenas. Я нашел интересный способ - нажать правой кнопкой на пакет -> свойства -> сортировка. Но сортировка не применяется, когда я сохраняю изменения. Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно сделать. Хочу, чтобы интерфейсы, классы и enums были в кучке а не в разброс.

Comment: (Никак, скорее всего) Переходи на IDEA, или хотя бы на Eclipse.

Comment: @Антон Сорокин для чего то ведь нужна вышеприведённая функция, значит есть.

Comment: @АлексейЗемцов боюсь, что Netbeans уже давно умер - вернее потерял свое значение и рыночную долю. Советую перейти под Intellij IDEA или хотя бы Eclipse

Comment: Хотел добавить, что именно поэтому маловероятно, что здесь найдутся люди работающие и знающие этот NetBeans - я лично в последний раз запускал его лет 5 назад наверное...